# Different Column for Distinct value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I've written this SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP (15) UserName, EventName, EventTime
FROM AttendanceEvents
WHERE UserName = 'Kareem'
```

Which results in :

[image]

How can I separate values into new columns for an Event?

The output I want is:

```
UserName | Login                | LogOut
Kareem    2015-04-13 01:43       2015-04-13 13:44
Kareem    2015-04-18 12:39       NULL
Kareem    2015-04-18 12:43       NULL
.
.
.
Kareem    2015-04-25 00:35       2015-04-25 05:21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation by taking min

```
select username,cast(eventtime as date) as d, min(case when eventname='IN' then eventtime end) as login,
min(case when eventname='OUT' then eventtime end) as logout
from tablename
group by username,cast(eventtime as date)
```

Comment: It produces the right answer as expected but, leaves all the other values for INs and OUTs, in our case, Only ONE login and Logout value for every User is shown, while I need all of them. What's the fix?

Comment: can you please modify your expected output, then perhaps it easy to understand

Comment: Done @fa06. I want it to be separable by the UserName. Show all values for a particular User with all Ins and Outs and I can vary my query with all the results for  Some other user as well?

Comment: Modified the answer, you just need to add date part of eventtime @DawoodAbbas

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you Sir. @fa06

Comment: @DawoodAbbas . . . You accepted this answer although it explicitly does not return the results you specify.  This returns one row per day, but your expected results quite clearly has two rows for Kareem on 2015-04-18.